# Run file with gdbserver --multi

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

Given:

```
gdbserver --multi :2345
```

is running on remote machine. I can connect to it with `gdb`:

```
(gdb) target remote 192.168.10.248:2345
Remote debugging using 192.168.10.248:2345
The target is not running (try extended-remote?)

(gdb) target extended-remote 192.168.10.248:2345
Remote debugging using 192.168.10.248:2345
```

What next? How to run some file, say `a.out` on remote machine and debug it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What next?

```
(gdb) set remote exec-file a.out
(gdb) file a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4015ab: file 1.cpp, line 60.
(gdb) r
```

- `set remote exec-file a.out` is used to set the program which you
  want to debug in the target.
- `file a.out` is used to load the debugging symbols from the program
  in the host.

See full example for `gdbserver --multi` here: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/04/gdbserver-example//